# I want to enable a disabled input format

Tags: 8, input-formats

I considered 'restricted HTML' as unnecessary and set it ‘disable’.
Because I thought it possible to re-enable.
However, I have not found a disabled format on UI.

Since there is no choice, I decided to newly register.
The same registration as the default machine name 'restricted_html' conflicts.
Imagine the data is left somewhere.
I could not find it even if I looked for a database.
Is it possible to restore by setting file or something?

I am using Drupal 8.4.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known issue, though you are warned before you disable the textformat that this cannot be undone. See the issue [Disabled text formats can't be seen in the GUI](https://www.drupal.org/node/2502637) and the comment [#60](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2502637#comment-10605964):

> It is possible to reenable disabled text formats with the
>   configuration manager:
>
> - go to /admin/config/development/configuration/single/export
> - choose Text format as the Configuration type
> - choose the disabled text format as Configuration Name
> - copy the configuration
> - go to /admin/config/development/configuration/single/import
> - again choose Text format as the Configuration type
> - paste the configuration
> - **change "status" from false to true**
> - click on import
>
> Voilá, the text format is available again. This is working but not
>   user friendly :(

Comment: Thank you. I understood the setting's export and import. Suddenly, we could not import with the error of L10n_client module. I will execute the Drush command of the message below.

Comment: After solving the problem of l10n_client module, this problem was solved by your method.

Answer (score 2):

More intuitive with drush :

```
drush ev '\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable("editor.editor.<EDITOR_ID>")->set("status",true)->save(true);'
drush ev '\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable("filter.format.<EDITOR_ID>")->set("status",true)->save(true);'
```

**Or**

Programmatically :

```
\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('editor.editor.<EDITOR_ID>')
                        ->set('status',true)
                        ->save(true);
\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable("filter.format.<EDITOR_ID>")
                        ->set("status",true)
                        ->save(true);
```

Comment: Please tell me what EDITOR_ID is.
Is it UUID?

Comment: Editor id are "basic_html", "full_html" and "plain_text" by default. I guess you talk about "basic_html".

Comment: Thanks.
My case is 'restricted_html'. 
The drupal command ran without error, but admin/config/content/formats has ‘The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.’

Comment: Error log is 
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "" plugin does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 52 of /Users/hogehoge/Sites/devdesktop/d8_drupalproject_tmgmt_moc1/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).

Comment: This error is not related to that command, have you missspelled your id ?

Comment: If you did with basic_html , remove it drush ev '\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable("editor.editor.basic_html")->delete();'

Comment: After drush ev '\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable("editor.editor.restricted_html")->delete();' , error has disappeared. I'll try again.

Comment: I solved it with Configuration Manager.
Thank you for telling me other ways.